# How is iPad/iPhone multitasking implemented?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, multitasking

How is iPad/iPhone multitasking implemented ? How is this implemented at the language level? I have read freeze dried anyone knows the details?

Answer (score 0):

use this method to implement

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

Comment: Read the question again—he's not asking about how to use multitasking in an app, he's asking how the “freezing” stuff actually works behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

You can never know these things for sure as the OS is not open source, having said that it seems plausible that it is similar to the unix command `kill -STOP`